# Trouble getting started with Spring Roo and GWT

Tags: java, gwt, maven, spring-roo

I am trying to get started with SpringRoo and GWT after seeing the keynote... unfortunately I am stuck at this issue. I successfully created the project using Roo and added the persistence, the entities and when I perform the command "perform package" I get this error:

```
23/5/10 12:10:13 AM AST: [ERROR] ApplicationEntityTypesProcessor cannot be resolved
23/5/10 12:10:13 AM AST: [ERROR] ApplicationEntityTypesProcessor cannot be resolved to a type
23/5/10 12:10:13 AM AST: [WARN] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
23/5/10 12:10:13 AM AST: [WARN] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
23/5/10 12:10:13 AM AST: Build errors for helloroo; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0:compile (default) on project helloroo: Compiler errors : 
error at import tp.gwt.request.ApplicationEntityTypesProcessor;
```

I see this in the Maven console and can't complete the build... I know there is some jar missing but how and why? Because I downloaded all the latest version including GWT milestone release. Any idea why this error is occurring? How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like [ROO-868](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/ROO-868) (I'm not saying it's the same issue, but it's similar). I am not very familiar with Roo development workflow but... what happens if you run `mvn gwt:run` as suggested?

Answer (score 0):

am not sure about this.but according my knowledge this problem may be occur by mavan does not downloading all required resources .